# Drop down menu in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a problem with action bar and menu. I want to create drop down menu in action bar.I have icon which when I click on it I get drop down list with items where item have icon and title. Is there any standard icon in action bar or I need create something else?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Are you asking for help with creating a navigation drop down? Creating a sub-menu? You need icons for the action bar?

Comment: I need create sub-menu where items have icon and title, but I want set icon this submenu by myself.

Comment: Submenus in Android cannot have icons, only text. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Study these links  [link1](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Dropdown)

[link2](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/04/customizing-action-bar.html) Hope this will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Add Menus items to your `ActionBar` and set  `android:showAsAction="never"` , ActionBar will create a dropdown menu and display all your Menu items if there is no room on the standard action bar.

You can also change the style using `android:actionDropDownStyle`.

Read [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html)